# POST from AngularJS to slim framework

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, api, slim

Hi im making a form that send a search request to my slim API

the form works, data gets posted but in slim i get the data as a string:

form post angular
                $scope.submitForm = function() {
                    console.log("--> Submitting form");

```
                $http({

                    url: "http://localhost/c2dapi/search",
                    data: $scope.searchForm,
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

                }).success(function(data){

                    console.log("OK", data)

                }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)})
```

};

```
//SLIM API
$app->post('/search', function () use ($app){
  $request = $app->request();
  $body = $request->getBody();
var_dump($body);
});
```

now this is my first angular + rest aproach so maybe im wrong but when i var dump the body in slim i get OK string(18) "{"zipCode":"3434"}"

I know there are ways to break up this string in php to get the value, but is this the right way or can i get the data also as a php array in slim ?

Comment: I have no idea how slim works but have you tried encoding the request body with json_decode: `$json = json_decode($request->getBody())`

Comment: $input = json_decode($body, true); will convert the json into array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to decode the json string once you receive the request. Using the json_decode function